# Get distinct values in full outer join

Tags: sql

I have two tables that have distinct ids

```
Table 1    Table 2    Desired Result
+----+     +----+     +--------------------+
| id |     | id |  =  | id | a     | b     |
+----+     +----+     +--------------------+
| 1  |     | 2  |     | 1  | TRUE  | FALSE |
| 2  |     | 3  |     | 2  | TRUE  | TRUE  |
| 3  |     | 4  |     | 3  | TRUE  | TRUE  |
+----+     +----+     | 4  | FALSE | TRUE  |
                      +--------------------+
```

and I'm querying them like this:

```
SELECT
  id,
  table1.id IS NOT NULL as a,
  table2.id IS NOT NULL as b,
FROM table1
FULL JOIN table2
  USING (id)
```

If id is unique in table1 and in table2 is it guarunteed to be unique in the resulting table?  Is there a better way to get my desired result, or is the best way?

Answer (score 0):

i would try this option

```
  select id
       ,max(case when a is null then 'FALSE' else 'TRUE' end) as a
       ,max(case when b is null then 'FALSE' else 'TRUE' end) as b
  from (
         select id,'TRUE' as a,null as b
           from table1
         union all
         select id,null as a,'TRUE' as b
           from table2
        )x
group by x.id
```